# How to implement mapbox SDK v10 to android app written in Java?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I am trying to implement Mapbox SDK v10 in my android app that's completely written in Java.
I have been able to show the map and even the camera points to my current location but when I am trying to put a marker on the map I can't find the relevant codes in java because only kotlin codes are present

`// Create an instance of the Annotation API and get the PointAnnotationManager. val annotationApi = mapView?.annotations val pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView) // Set options for the resulting symbol layer. val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions() // Define a geographic coordinate. .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(18.06, 59.31)) // Specify the bitmap you assigned to the point annotation // The bitmap will be added to map style automatically. .withIconImage(YOUR_ICON_BITMAP) // Add the resulting pointAnnotation to the map. pointAnnotationManager?.create(pointAnnotationOptions)`

So I have 2 questions-
1)How can I put an annotation or marker on the map using java?
2)On the other hand I have been able to use Mapbox SDK v9 successfully ,but it's marked as legacy so can I still use this SDK in my app or there can be some problem in the future if I use SDK v9?

Answer (score 1):

These are the codes for adding a marker, polyline of polygon in mapbox10 java:

```
private void AddMarker(Point point)
{
    AnnotationPlugin annotationApi = AnnotationPluginImplKt.getAnnotations(mapView);
    CircleAnnotationManager circleAnnotationManager = CircleAnnotationManagerKt.createCircleAnnotationManager(annotationApi, new AnnotationConfig());

    CircleAnnotationOptions circleAnnotationOptions = new CircleAnnotationOptions()
            .withPoint(point)
            .withCircleRadius(7.0)
            .withCircleColor("#ee4e8b")
            .withCircleStrokeWidth(1.0)
            .withDraggable(true)
            .withCircleStrokeColor("#ffffff");

    circleAnnotationManager.create(circleAnnotationOptions);
}

private void DrawPolyLine() {

    AnnotationPlugin annotationApi = AnnotationPluginImplKt.getAnnotations(mapView);
    PolylineAnnotationManager polylineAnnotationManager = PolylineAnnotationManagerKt.createPolylineAnnotationManager(annotationApi,new AnnotationConfig());
    PolylineAnnotationOptions polylineAnnotationOptions = new PolylineAnnotationOptions()
           .withPoints(pointList)
            .withLineColor("#ee4e8b")
            .withLineWidth(4);
    polylineAnnotationManager.create(polylineAnnotationOptions);

}

private void DrawPolygon(List<Point> myPointList) {

    List<Point> pointList = myPointList;
    pointList.add(myPointList.get(0));
    List<List<Point>> polygonList = new ArrayList<>();
    polygonList.add(pointList);


    polygonAnnotationManager = PolygonAnnotationManagerKt.createPolygonAnnotationManager(annotationApi,new AnnotationConfig());
    PolygonAnnotationOptions polygonAnnotationOptions = new PolygonAnnotationOptions()
            .withPoints(polygonList)
            .withFillColor("#ee4e8b")
            .withFillOpacity(0.5);
    PolygonAnnotation polygonAnnotation = polygonAnnotationManager.create(polygonAnnotationOptions);

}
```

remember for marker annotation we have to types: Point annotation and Circle annotation but their implementation of them are the same.

Comment: Can you add code for using TransitionOptions.